# Gradle - run mongoDB scripts

Tags: mongodb, build, gradle

In our gradle script we run some mysql scripts with gradle using jdbc.
My question: is there any similar way to execute scripts for mongo through gradle?

Here  is how we execute mysql scripts thorugh gradle:

```
def props = [user: mySqlLoginName, password: mySqlPassword, allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(mySqlUrl, props, driver)
File allModification = file("src/main/database/updateScript.sql")
String fileContents = allModification.text
println "\nUpdating mySql"
sql.execute fileContents
```

thanks!

Comment: To give someone a chance to answer this question, you'd have to describe in detail how you are running the mysql scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code above is really outside a task declaration, it means that you are running this query for every single Gradle invocation, which is probably not what you want. Anyway, the code is using Groovy's `Sql` class and no particular Gradle features. Likewise, you can use any Mongo client library to access Mongo in a similar way.

You'll need to declare a dependency on the Mongo client library in a `buildscript` block. This will allow Gradle to download the dependency and make it available to the build script. For details on how to declare a `buildscript` block, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).